# How can I play xbox 360 online games with my friends in Canada and Mexico?

Tags: xbox-network

I live in the US and recently I bought black ops 2 to play with my friends in Mexico but I when I tried to invite them to the game it wouldn't let me but it let me invite my friends in the us.Could somebody please tell me how to be able to play with them?Is it even possible?

Comment: It is possible. This sounds like a problem with your home network, rather than Xbox live

Comment: Research NAT Type.

Comment: Maybe your friends in Mexico don't have a good enough Network connection.